# arduino read in pyfirmata gives output as none

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino-uno, firmata

I wrote a basic code for reading values from analog pin 0(I have a light sensor attached to it and the output is coming at analog pin 0) in python3 using pyfirmata, but it is giving the output as none no matter what. I tried the same code in arduino IDE and that is  giving the right answer. Please help.

Code is :

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time
board = Arduino('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411')

it = util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

board.analog[0].enable_reporting()

while True : 
            print (board.analog[0].read())
            time.sleep(1)
```

Even when it gives an output after few seconds, it gives 0.29 which isn't actually the sensor value that comes on serial monitor. That value varies between 0 and 1023 and is relatively quite larger than this.

Answer (score 2):

The analog  pins    of  Arduino linearly    translate   the input   voltages    between 0   and +5V to  0
and 1023.   However,    in   pyFirmata ,    the values  between 0   and +5V are linearly    translated
into    the float   values  of  0   and 1.0.    For example,    if  the voltage at  the analog  pin is  1V, an
Arduino program will    measure a   value   somewhere   around  204,    but you will    receive the
float   value   as  0.2 while   using   pyFirmata’s  read()     method  in  Python.

Comment: Nice info! Your answer explains the (seemingly) strange values (e.g., 0.29). Any idea why the OP was seeing `None` as an output value sometimes, though?

Comment: For that you have to define the pin as an input pin. By defining the pin as an input you will be able to read values. Also you can cross check by using firmata GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start an Iterator thread before reading

```py
board = pyfirmata.Arduino("COM5") # change com port  
board.digital[3].mode = pyfirmata.INPUT  
it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)  
it.start()  
board.digital[3].read()
```

Most of the time it work, but sometimes None still show up. Sometimes `time.sleep` can help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do an if conditional first, something like this (and try running analogfirmata):

```
while True:
 if board.analog[0].read() == None:
  pass
 else:
  print("board.analog[0].read()")
```